# Keep responsive absolute centered div when browser resized

Tags: jquery, browser, resize, center

I have a test website I am working on converted a small app i made to be responsive. Its working but one thing is broken; When you resize the browser window the centered div does not stay centered when you resize vertically. Resizing horizontally works fine.

You can check it out by clicking this link: http://www.friendlierpizza.com/index2.php Now just scroll down and click: STORE HOURS. You will see the modal, and try to resize the browser vertically and it fails.

In the included `behavior.js` files on lines 71, and 90 is where I think the code should be. Or look at copy/pasted.

```
function resizeModal() {
    if ($currentId === false) return;
    var winW = $(window).width();
    $currentId.css('left', winW / 2 - $currentId.width() / 2);
}

$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("selected"); 
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
    $('#mask').hide(0);
    $('.window').hide(0);
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#mask').fadeTo(0, 0.8);
    var winH = $(window).height();
    $currentId = $(id);

    $currentId.css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);

    resizeModal();
    $currentId.fadeIn(500);
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Comment: your resizeModal method are changing just the 'left' attribute. it should change also the 'top' attribute.

Comment: i see that, just not sure of the proper syntax...

Comment: is the same as you change the 'left' attribute using the 'width' of window and element. But in this case, change the 'width' to 'height' and 'left' to 'top.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is this what you are loking for.

```
function resizeModal() {
    if ($currentId === false) return;
    var winW = $(window).width();
    $currentId.css('left', winW / 2 - $currentId.width() / 2);
    var winH = $(window).height();
    $currentId.css('top', winH / 2 - $currentId.height() / 2);
}
```